# Translating XPath to LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am having trouble with translating the following XPath queries into LINQ. I am not sure what to do with the position() method as I can't find a LINQ equivalent.

```
(//table[@border='1'])[1]//tr[position() > 1 and position() < last()]
```

Also, I can't find a LINQ version of the `.//` in the query:

```
.//div[span/@title='Event group']
```

Could someone help me translate these?

Comment: Can't you use XPath with LINQ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342176(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I'm parsing HTML, not XML (the reason I am asking this question is because HtmlAgilityParser does not support XPath on Android apps, which is what I am developing for, so I am trying to translate all my XPath into LINQ)

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack should have support for LINQ built-in...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part of your XPath `(//table[@border='1'])[1]`, can be translated roughly to the following LINQ (assume `doc` is an instance of `XDocument`) :

```
doc.Descendants("table")
   .Where(o => (string)o.Attribute("border") == "1")
   .FirstOrDefault()?
```

And this expression `//tr[position() > 1 and position() < last()]`, translates roughly to :

```
.Descendants("tr").Where(o => {
    var trs = o.Parent.Elements("tr").ToList();
    var position = trs.IndexOf(o)+1;  //since XPath position index starts from 1
    return position > 1 && position < trs.Count;
})
```

From the two examples above, you should be able to see how to express `//`, `position()`, and `@attribute` in LINQ. Translating your 2nd XPath is left as an excercise :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: @user2396873: Are you using HTML Agility Pack? It doesn't have the same APIs as LINQ to XML has.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to do a literal translation, you should do a query that is actually equivalent.

The query is selecting rows skipping the first and last row. There are far more efficient ways to get that.

The first part of the query is selecting the first table that has a border.  Then take the rows skipping the first, then taking all but the last.  There's no way to reliably find out what the last is without taking all and counting.

```
(//table[@border='1'])[1]//tr[position() > 1 and position() < last()]
```

```
var table = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("table")
    .Where(e => e.Attributes["border"] == "1")
    .First();
var rows = table.Descendants("tr")
    .Skip(1) // skip the first row
    .ToList();
var result = rows.Take(rows.Count - 1); // take all up to the last
```

---

For the other part, the equivalent of `//` is calling `Descendants()`.

```
.//div[span/@title='Event group']
```

```
var query =
    from d in e.Descendants("div")
    where d.Elements("span").Any(s => s.Attribute["title"] == "Event group")
    select d;
```